# iOS 5: numberOfRowsInSection doesn't work

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've got a tableView in storybord and UISegmentedControl to populate the over mentioned table with with different data and different design. My problem is that numberOfRowsInSection meth doesn't react when I switch UISegmentedControl.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
{
    return [self.items count];
    NSLog(@"Nominals: %d",self.items.count);
}
if(self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex==1)
{
    return [self.coinageArr count];
    NSLog(@"Coinage: %d",self.coinageArr.count);
}
//return 0; Complains about no return.
}
```

Well, NSLogs do not work while navigating. And how to return NSInteger in this case?

Thanx in advance.

EDIT: For shannoga

segment controller switch method:

```
-(IBAction)segmentValueChaged:(id)sender
{
switch (self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex) 
{
    case 0:
    {
         DBAccess *access=[[DBAccess alloc]init];
        self.items=[access returnNominals:self.entityID nk:fromPeriod];
        [access closeDataBase];            
        self.tableView.hidden=NO;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
         break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        DBAccess *access=[[DBAccess alloc]init];
        self.coinageArr=[access returnCoinage:fromPeriod period:self.entityID];
        self.tableView.hidden=NO;
        [self.tableView reloadData];

        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you reloading the table when the selected segment of the segmented control changes?

Comment: Yes, in -(IBAction)segmentValueChaged:(id)sender method I call [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: As already said, you have to move the NSLog calls before the return. Also, you should use a if-else construct here instead of two ifs.

Comment: O.K so why don't you use 1 array 'self.items' for example for both cases ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The NSLog won't work because the return take effect before you get to this line and it will never be executed.

Change it to:

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
{
     NSLog(@"Nominals: %d",self.items.count);
    return [self.items count];
}
if(self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex==1)
{
   NSLog(@"Coinage: %d",self.coinageArr.count);
    return [self.coinageArr count];
}
//return 0; Complains about no return.
}
```

- Can you show the method that you call when the UISegmentedControl is changed?
- Pay attention that you don't need to set 2 if statements you could use `else`.
- As @Ryan said you should use `[tableview reloadData]` on your UISegmentedControl change. Then it will be better if you change the  `self.items` array in your `valueChanged` method and leave the `numberOfRowsInSection` with out a change so it will look like that:

  ```
    - (void)valueChanged:(id)sender
    {
      if(self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
      {
          self.items = what ever
      }else{
          self.items = what ever
      }
      [tableview reloadData];
     }

      - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
       return [self.items count];
     }
  ```

Good Luck

Comment: @shannoga Is right. I'd say its best practice to leave logic out of the `numberOfRowsInSection` method and move it into the method where the interaction is actually occurring.

Comment: But what about return in numberOfRowsInSection? I have to return integer. Should I define local int var and assign to it the value of rows and return it? Or i can return 0.

Comment: Ah. Yes...return [self.items count]; if using the same array.

Answer (score 1):

After you change the value of the UISegmentedControl you need to update the table. You can do it easily with `[tableView reloadData];` or you can use something like `[tableView reloadSection:0 withTableViewAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];`

The best place to do this is probably in a valueChanged method for your control.

```
// Wherever you init your UISegmentedControl
segmentedControl addTarget:self selector:@selector(valueChanged:) forEvent:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)valueChanged:(id)sender
{
    [tableview reloadData];
}
```